# call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null using laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-formrequest

I keep on getting the following error when I try to upload images. Does anybody have any idea how to solve this? I'm confused about what to do next.

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null

https://flareapp.io/share/dmkydl73#F42

**Controller**

```
public function singalprojectaction(Request $request)
{
    $validation = validator::make($request->all(), [
        'select_file_one' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        'select_file_Two' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        'select_file_Three' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        'select_file_Four' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        'select_file_Five' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    if ($validation->passes()) {
        $select_project = $request->get('select_project');
        $project_name = $request->get('project_name');
        $Client_name = $request->get('Client_name');
        $Completion_date = $request->get('Completion_date');
        $Duration = $request->get('Duration');
        $Description = $request->get('Description');
        $select_file_one = $request->file('select_file_one');
        $select_file_Two = $request->file('select_file_Two');
        $select_file_Three = $request->file('select_file_Three');
        $select_file_Four = $request->file('select_file_Four');
        $select_file_Five = $request->file('select_file_Five');

        $new_name_one = mt_rand().'.'.$select_file_one->getClientOriginalName();
        $select_file_one->move(public_path('projects'), $new_name_one);
        $new_name_Two = mt_rand().'.'.$select_file_Two->getClientOriginalName();
        $select_file_Two->move(public_path('projects'), $new_name_Two);
        $new_name_Three = mt_rand().'.'.$select_file_Three->getClientOriginalName();
        $select_file_Three->move(public_path('projects'), $new_name_Three);
        $new_name_Four = mt_rand().'.'.$select_file_Four->getClientOriginalName();
        $select_file_Four->move(public_path('projects'), $new_name_Four);
        $new_name_Five = mt_rand().'.'.$select_file_Five->getClientOriginalName();
        $select_file_Five->move(public_path('projects'), $new_name_Five);

        $query = DB::table('single_portfolio')->insert([
            'project_id' => $select_project, 'Project_name' => $project_name,
            'Client_Name' => $Client_name, 'Completion_date' => $Completion_date
            , 'Duration' => $Duration, 'Description' => $Description, 'image_one' => $new_name_one, 'image_two' =>
                $new_name_Two,
            'image_three' => $new_name_Three, 'image_four' => $new_name_Four, 'image_five' => $new_name_Five
        ]);

        if ($query) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('messages', 'Data Is Successfully Inserted');
        }

    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell the `$request->file('select_file_Two');` returns `null`; This means most likely that no files was selected for the input with name `select_file_Two`, make sure the names is the same casing and not `select_file_two`.
If all files are required you can add a `required` to the validator like so

```
 `require|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048`
```

or if the are optional you could check if the file exist before hand like so

```
if(!is_null($select_file_one)){
  $new_name_one = rand() . '.' . $select_file_one->getClientOriginalName();
  $select_file_one->move(public_path('projects'), $new_name_one);
}
```

and skill all the files that were not send.

Also something to note here is you are using rand() to generate the the new name this may in time overwrite files. I would suggest adding a timestamp like so

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
$name = rand() . '_' . now()->timestamp . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

Answer (score 1):

if your codes are ok , which seems so, most of the time is you html form.
take a look at your form and see if `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is included in your form tag, otherwise the files wont be sent.the hole form part should be like this :

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="URL">
    </form>
```